# nth-child(1) is affecting other elements too

Tags: html, css

I want the first element to be bold and to affect that I used `nth:child(1)`. But for some reason the elements in the `<ul>` are becoming bold too. Why is that happening and how to fix this bug?

```css
.sub-box1 :nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-box1">
  <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
    <li><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `nth-child` pseudo-class to the `li` element like this:

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-box1">
  <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
    <li><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `:nth-child` pseudo-class should be read as "An element that is the nth-child of its parent"